# Variable string use in Array php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to use variable string in Array like I saved array value any file or document or variable and I want to use it in array but I am failed to do so.

```
$var = "'title' => 'This is my title','name' => 'My name is John'";

$ar = array($var); 

echo $ar['title'].'<br>'.$ar['name'];
```

Error I am getting

```
Notice: Undefined index: title
Notice: Undefined index: name
```

Comment: Have a look into this SO question, maybe it helps with what you want to archive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267434/php-how-to-turn-a-string-that-contains-an-array-expression-in-an-actual-array

Answer (score 1):

You can use **strtok()** function for splitting a string into an array with a delimiter.

Try the below code:

```
<?php
  $var = "'title' => 'This is my title','name' => 'My name is John'";
  $ar = strtok($var,",");
  while ($ar!==false)
  {
    echo "$ar<br>";
    $ar=strtok(",");
  }
 ?>
```

Here I have used the "**,**" as delimiter.

**Output:**

> 'title' => 'This is my title'
>
> 'name' => 'My name is John'

Comment: Yeah but I want to assign value of title and name in variable so I can use it anywhere like
`$mytitle = $var['title'];
echo $mytitle;

Output will be 
'This is my title'`

Comment: Please think that array is not a map to have the key value pair. What you are asking can not be achieved with Array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ar = array('title' => 'This is my title','name' => 'My name is John');
```

Comment: I know I can do like this but I want to use variable and assume array value is saved in variable same like this no changing
`$var = "'title' => 'This is my title','name' => 'My name is John'";`

Comment: `$var` is being stored as a single dimension value on 0th position. So if you echo out `$ar[0]` will give you the the $var value. You can use `explode` to get the array. `explode(',', $var);`